# Google Analytics - add script to functions.php

Tags: functions, google-analytics

I want to connect google analytics to my site. I don't want to do it through the MonsterInsights plug-in. I added this script to functions.php. Will it work?

```
<?php
/**
 * Add functions files
 *
 * @package Virtue Theme
 */

/**
 * Language setup
 */
function virtue_lang_setup() {
    load_theme_textdomain( 'virtue', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
}

add_action('wp_head', 'my_analytics', 20);
function my_analytics() {
?>
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-00000000-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-00000000-1');
</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: You can check if it works by adding it and looking in the google cloud console. Keep in mind that when your theme updates this will be lost though, you would be better off turning the snippet into a plugin instead of modifying a theme

Comment: You could check to make sure it's being outputted by inspecting the source code after loading your website. and search for the gtag id using ctrl+f

Comment: Obviously make sure you add a valid analytics ID as UA-00000000-1 will not work. You can find this in the Property section of Analytics.